# Can we have "Considering relocation" option in Jobs profile?

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I'm sometimes contacted by companies who hire for some particular offices around the world, however currently I'm not considering relocation as a possible option for me.

Can we have a possibility to reflect this in the Developer Story (or Jobs, or whatever it is called right now) profile?

Answer (score 1):

You can indicate your interest in particular locations by adding them to the list of locations in your [match preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/users/jobsearch/current):

[image: Location Prefs]

You can also specify whether you require a visa for that location.

These get surfaced in our Candidate Search product to employers. Is this the kind of thing you're looking for?

Comment: I've seen this, and I have this filled accordingly, but people seem to treat this as "where am I currently", or something.True that the title "Where you'd like to work" seems unambiguous, but this raises the question is how is to presented to the potential employers/recruiters?

Comment: @BartoszKP that's legit; we have a lot of enhancements coming to candidate search in the coming weeks, I'll flag it up for the team to investigate

Comment: Great thanks! And thanks for finding the duplicate :-)